# JMeter Cookie Manager

Tags: apache, cookies, jmeter

I am using JMeter to make a simple login test on my website. I have a Thread Group which contains a Cookie Manager, an HTTP request to the root page, then an HTTP Post which posts a username and password, and then a Results view. When I run the test and view the response, the results show that the first HTTP request correctly calls `set-cookie` with the JSessionID, but the second HTTP request that POSTS credentials has no cookies - shouldn't this cookie be posted from the Cookie Manager? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most apps that I've tested, I don't see the actual cookie information after the initial request.

If your session isn't being maintained, there are a few quick things to check:

1. there are no hard coded JSessionID values in the HTTP Requests;

2. try different cookie manager types - different applications expect different settings.